# How can I make an element overlap elements in higher stacking contexts?

Tags: html, css

In this [example](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/790/understanding_zindex_04.png), is there any way to make Div #4, Div #5, and Div #6 higher than Div #1? I've read that z-index only applies to elements *within* the same stacking context. So here, Div 4,5, and 6 are within the stacking context of Div #3.

In another example, as shown [here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lgFiq), and change the **main div** left property to something like 10%, the child element is being overlapped by the body element.

```
main div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Is there any way for them to overlap other elements in 'higher' stacking contexts?

Comment: The example you just added has nothing to do with `z-index` or stacking contexts. Change `overflow:auto` on `main` to `overflow:visible`. [Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWoWvW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `#2` a `z-index` higher or equal with `#1`'s and any `position` value, except `static`. (If you change `#2`'s `z-index` to `5`, it will make all children of `#2` render above `#1`.)

More on `z-index` and [stacking contexts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385907/why-isnt-z-index-working/41385975#41385975). I also made a toy (snippet) there that can be used to dynamically cycle through different `z-index` values in a stack so you can visualize what happens.

Another way of making children of `#2` render above `#1` would be to set `position:static` on `#1`. This way its `z-index` will no longer apply.

Comment: I think I may have made the question a little unclear. I'm already aware Div#2 can be above Div#1, they're in the same stacking context. So in the example above, is there any way for Div 4,5 and 6 to render above Div #1 seeing as Div#1 is in a 'higher' stacking context then Div 4, 5, and 6??

Comment: If both `#1` and `#2` have positive values of `z-index` and `#1` is higher than `#2` and they both have values of `position` other than `static`, then ***no***. All the children of `#2` are in a `z-index` "bubble" at their parent's `z-index`.

Comment: So, a dirty way of doing it is setting `position:static` on `#1` -  (updated the answer).

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the div `#2` ! please read the question carefully. It is about `#1` and `#3`.